# Javascript Adding Time for a Future Date

Tags: javascript, date

I looked at some other questions, and don't see my specific problem, so please excuse me if it has been asked or answered.

What I am trying to do is figure out a simple "payment" calculator, and provide some additional information, such as the first payment date, and the last.

In some cases, the day of the last payment works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
var myDate = new Date();

var odo = document.contract.firstPaymentDate.value;
var n = odo.split("/"); 
var month = n[0];
var day = n[1];
var year = n[2];

var oldDateObj = new Date(year, month, day);
var newDateObj = new Date(oldDateObj.getTime() + ((document.contract.totalNumberRegularPayments.value - 1)*1209600*1000));
var dd = newDateObj.getDate();
var mm = newDateObj.getMonth();
var y = newDateObj.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = mm + '/'+ dd + '/'+ y;
document.contract.lastPaymentDate.value = someFormattedDate;
```

So I take the first payment date, and add 1209600 seconds times the number of payments (minus 1 since they have "already" paid the first).

This is based on starting at a specific day that can be chosen by the user.

So my example is 156 BiWeekly payments (so 155 for the calculations), which works out to 6 years.  If I choose the date of the 1st, I get 10/01/2013 as the start, but 9/11/2019 as the end (First on a Tuesday, last on a Wednesday).

For the 15th (9/15/2013 - a Sunday - to 8/24/2019 - a Saturday)
For the 20th (9/20/2013 - a Friday - to 8/29/2013 - a Thursday)

So since sometimes it's a day later, and sometimes a day ahead, I can't just +1 to `var dd = newDateObj.getDate();`

I'm really baffled as to what's going on, and I'm hoping someone out there either has some experience with this, or someone that knows what the heck I might be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Note that months in JavaScript are zero indexed, so `new Date(year, --month, day)` and `var mm = newDateObj.getMonth() + 1`. Also, instead of `oldDateObj.getTime()` you can just use `+oldDateObj`. Might be a bit obfuscated though. Finally, only about 5% of the world's population uses month/day/year format, so make sure it's clear that's the format you expect and are presenting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to add a number of weeks, just add 7 times as many days, e.g.

```
var now = new Date();
// Add two weeks
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 14);
```

So if you have 24 fortnightly payments:

```
var now = new Date();
// Add 24 fortnights (48 weeks)
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 24 * 14);
```

or

```
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 24 * 2 * 7);
```

whatever you think is clearest.

If you want to have a start and end date:

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date(+start);
end.setDate(end.getDate() + 24 * 14);

alert('Start on: ' + start + '.\nEnd in 24 fortnights: ' + end);
```

#### Edit

Here's a working example:

```
<script>

function calcLastPayment(start, numPayments) {
  if (typeof start == 'string') {
    start = stringToDate(start);
  }

  var end = new Date(+start);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + --numPayments * 14)
  return end;
}

// Expect date in US format m/d/y
function stringToDate(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/)
  return new Date(s[2], --s[0], s[1])
}

</script>

<form>
 <table>
  <tr><td>Enter first payment date (m/d/y):
      <td><input name="start">
  <tr><td>Enter number of payments:
      <td><input name="numPayments">
  <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Calc end date" onclick="
           this.form.end.value = calcLastPayment(this.form.start.value, this.form.numPayments.value)
           ">
  <tr><td>Last payment date:
      <td><input readonly name="end">
  <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="reset">
 </table>
</form>
```

Given a first payment date of Thursday, 5 September and 3 repayments it returns Thursday 3 October, which seems correct to me (5 and 19 September and 3 October). It should work for any number of payments.

Comment: Thanks, but the first payment is not always today.  It's always set out a certain number of days, but that all depends on the start date.  As of today, the start dates available are the ones I outlined in my question.  So depending on which one is taken, I have to figure out the end date.  I would love to use `now`, but that won't work.  Do you have a suggestion to configure start to be the start date calculated (which is working good)?  If so, your last bit of code should work for me.

Comment: Update...last bit of code still doesn't work.  I end up with the +1 day or -1 day, depending on the start date.  **confused**

Comment: The strategy is the same. You create a Date object (it doesn't matter how, your code is fine for that), then just add 14 times the number of fortnights to the date. So if your first payment is 3 September, the next is 3 + 14 = 17 September, the next is 17 + 14 = 1 October and so on.

Comment: I took out the button, and made called the function on a drop down onChange, and also changed the function to this: `function calcLastPayment(start, numPayments) {
  if (typeof start == 'string') {
    start = stringToDate(start);
  }

  var end = new Date(+start);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + --numPayments * 14)
 var dd = end.getDate();
 var mm = end.getMonth() + 1;
 var y = end.getFullYear();
 var someFormattedDate = mm + '/'+ dd + '/'+ y;
//end.toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
  return someFormattedDate;
}` and now I get the formatted date returned properly.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to do this in a line or two of code.

I use `864e5` for the number of milliseconds in a day. Because `1000 milliseconds/second * 60 seconds/minute * 60 minutes/hour * 24 hours/day = 86400000 milliseconds/day` or `864e5`.

```
var now = new Date,
    day = 864e5,
    weekFromNow = new Date(+now + day * 7); //+now casts the date to an integer
```

- `+now` casts the date to an integer, the number of milliseconds.  `now.valueOf()` works too.
- `day * 7` or `864e5 * 7` is the number of milliseconds in a week.
- `new Date(...)` casts the number of milliseconds to a date again.

Sometimes you don't have to worry about casting the value back to a date.